# JS or JQuery Day Parting Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am trying to get this day part scheduler to work on my website: https://github.com/artsy/day-schedule-selector

[image]

However that one doesn't work as I am on JQuery 2.2 and I can't get it to run, despite lots of attempts. I have Bootstrap on my website as well I load the script from the plugin and I see no errors in the console about it having issues loading the script. I have the div setup with ID 'weekly-schedule' where I want the scheduler to appear and I call the script to load the Scheduler like so:

```
$("#weekly-schedule").dayScheduleSelector({
  days: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6],
  startTime: '09:50',
  endTime: '21:06',
  interval: 15
});
```

Then nothing, no errors and nothing is changed on the page and no scheduler appears. Can someone detail the steps they took to get it to work maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What _doesn't work_ ? This plugin works well for me with jQuery 2.2+.

Comment: @TGrif can you paste the code of how you have it setup and are you using Bootstrap in that test?

Comment: I just change the jQuery version (2.2.4) in the [demo](https://github.com/artsy/day-schedule-selector/blob/master/examples/index.html). Is this a Bootstrap conflict issue ?

Comment: Looks like the issue was a CSS issue causing the plugin to be unable to bind to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when combined with Bootstrap something goes wrong when it tries to generate the Table and bind to the `<div>`.

This can be corrected by changing some default class names and setting CSS.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate for future users on what _goes wrong_ and the adjustments you made in _some default class names_ and the CSS.